# Changing Chart type of Chart control in ASP.NET 4

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-4.0

How can I change the chart type of the chart control in ASP.NET 4. I have a drop down list that contains name of all the chart types.

This is the code I came up with :

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart2.Series["Series1"].ChartType =  (SeriesChartType)   
                 Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType),DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to call DataBind() on the chart to get it to rerender.

(If that's the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample but not using asp.net chart control, instead fusion charts.

http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AJAX%20sample&referringTitle=Documentation